# AppDelegate gets an error when i add firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I am creating a brand new xcode proj and it works fine, then I do in terminal and I install cocoa pods and I do pod init. I then go and add `firebase/core` to the pod file and do `pod install`. Then when I start up my `xcworkspace` I get: `UIApplicationMain` class must conform to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: That's not a lot to go on. What's you podFile look like? Did you add any code to your app? What's the delegate look like?

Answer (score 1):

I just created a new Xcode project and add Firebase SDK as per `Add the SDK` section of [Firebase Get Start guide for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

Not issue. You might want to try again create a new Xcode project from zero.

Btw. Make sure you close the Xcode project before you perform any `pod` command.